# How to make autocomplete suggestion multiselect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
      var currentFocus;
      inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
          var a, b, i, val = this.value;
          closeAllLists();
          if (!val) { return false;}
          currentFocus = -1;
          a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
          this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
              /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
              b = document.createElement("DIV");
              b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
              b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  closeAllLists();
              });
              a.appendChild(b);
            }
          }
      });
      inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
          if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
          } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
              if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
          }
      });
      function addActive(x) {
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
      }
      function removeActive(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
      }
      function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          closeAllLists(e.target);
      });
    }
    var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana"];
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>
```

In this code I have an autocomplete suggestion box which is working perfectly. Now, what I actually want? I want to make this auto suggestion with `multiselect` value where I want to get `multiple` value like as `a,b,c` but now it return only single value. So, How can I make this auto suggestion with `multi-select` value? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you should use bootstap multiselct.  https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/bootstrap-multiselect/